# How can you see the number of items in a list using the SDL Tridion 2011 GUI using Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

When you view list of items (e.g. in Folders, Structure Groups or the Publishing Queue) in the CMS using Internet Explorer. The status bar of the browser tells you how many items are in the view (or have been selected). Is there an easy way to see this information with Chrome or Firefox? I tried installing status bar add-ons for the browsers, but it doesn’t seem to work. This is very frustrating as it is important to know how many items there are in these views.

Comment: I must admit I recently reverted to the [CountItems PowerTool](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/CountItems) for that.

Comment: Great idea Frank. For those who don't know, the PowerTools are a community driven set of extensions available at http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_43B1609144D94562A394BB51FAC884B9) (login required):

> If you want to have additional information available about the current
>   state of its window, enable the browser Status Bar (visible at the
>   bottom of the screen):
>
> ```
> In Mozilla Firefox, select View > Status Bar
> In Microsoft Internet Explorer, select Tools > Toolbars > Status Bar
> In Google Chrome, this feature is not available
> ```

N

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Nuno. Whilst I think that is the 'official' answer, it seems that documentation may have been written for an older version of Firefox than mine (I have 10.0.2). I managed to enable a status bar (with an add-on), but I don't see the same info that I see in IE. I think I will make an ER for this.

Comment: That's very likely the case. Firefox 10 (and 9) are not officially supported clients as far as I understand...

Answer (score 3):

I noticed this when I first got my hands on SDL Tridion 2011 and created an 'idea' on the SDL website here: http://ideas.sdltridion.com/ideas/detail.asp?i=3686

Perhaps you could give it a vote?

If your customer really needs this information you could make a little gui extension to add it somewhere to the CME interface, this one would be a potential good one to extend (http://yoavniran.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/navigation-history-tridion-gui-extension/)

Comment: +1 on Ideas. @Mihai created a [count items service/tool](http://code.google.com/searchframe#cQzsE9pPe50/trunk/PowerTools.Model/Services/CountItems.svc.cs]) for the SDLTridion PowerTools as well.